# Another deleted answer

Tags: discussion

It seems that people here feel no compunctions about deleting answers. Here is another one that was gotten rid of for no reason I can see---- this one doesn't swear. Here's the question: [Which of Nietzsche writing would be a good introduction to his work?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2466/which-of-nietzsche-writing-would-be-a-good-introduction-to-his-work)

> If you insist on reading Nietzsche, you should start and end with the Geneology of Morals, which contains the core. There is no point in reading any more, or of reading the whole of the Geneology, because Nietzsche is a one-trick pony. He doesn't write about mathematics, nor about the mind, it's always an anti-egalitarian response to Socialism, and it only appeals to those degenerates that think they are somehow so much more special than anybody else.
>
> Although this isn't a direct answer, in order to understand Nietzsche, you should really start by reading
>
> - 120 Days of Sodom
> - Philosophy in the Bedroom
> - The Misfortunes of Virtue.
>
> Or any other (early) work by the Marquis de Sade. The short stories are especially illuminating in their sensitivity and frankness.
>
> The philosophy the Marquis de Sade explains is very similar to Nietzsche, except the sex is not implicit, but explicit, and graphic. You will get to the same basic philosophy more quickly and without self-censorship in Sade. The work of Sade has the benefit that, while the surface meaning is critical of God, the books are guaranteed to reveal God's true form to a sensitive reader, because Sade artfully set them to make the mind revolt against the horror of the vision he describes.
>
> The main difference with Nietzsche is that, unlike Sade, he takes the idea of a master-class destined to rule the weak, seriously, and writes books about a Darwinian society of monstrous evil, a society that was implemented in Nazi Germany.

Could someone undelete this, or tell me what is wrong with it? I am trying to point out that the philosophy of Nietzsche is borrowing heavily (without attribution) from the philosophy expounded by the Sadian villains. This is not even an original point of view--- many people have drawn parallels between Nietzsche and Kraft-Ebbering (sp?) catalogue as relates to sexual sadism, a catalogue which I believe is derived in large part from Sade.

Further, the Sadian philosophy is not only 100 years prior to Nietzsche, it is very frankly sexual, and very frankly concerned with overturning Christian limitations to power. The result is expounded in pornographic novels which are more philosophy than pornography.

My point here is that Nietzsche is not just a !@$#^@* Nazi #@&!, but he is a plagiarist as well.

Comment: "it only appeals to those degenerates that think they are somehow so much more special than anybody else." Really? This one is at least short enough for me to salvage without spending hours, I'll take a look at it. :)

Comment: @stoic: This answer is not constructive or appropriate. Don't waste your time. The problems are systemic, far beyond specific language or syntactical constructions. It will stay deleted...

Comment: @stoicfury: Please tell me what to change. Should I make it "De******* that think they are somehow so much more special than anybody else?" Please _don't edit it_--- tell me what is wrong with it, and I'll do it. Just an aside--- It is possible that there are truly superior people, but if you think you're one of them, you're not.

Comment: @CodyGray: What are the problems? Aside from expressing a point of view you don't like, that is. There are those who would like to protect Nietzsche from honest criticism, and lock him up behind a wall of academic smoke-screens. I would like an honest conversation. This point of view is not expressed in the written answers, it exists in the world (at least in me, and in a handful of anti-Nietzsche books I've scanned), and I don't see any reason it should not be expressed here.

Comment: I have no vested interest in sheltering Nietzsche from any type of criticism, nor am I interested in censoring your freedom of expression. But you're attempting to express yourself in an extremely unconstructive way, and for your sake, I'd encourage you to rethink your course of action. Moreover, you're expressing yourself in a venue wherein it is inappropriate. My answer below contains more details, but perhaps the root of the problem is that you "would like an honest conversation". An answer to a question about which Nietzsche book one should read is not the place for that.

Comment: I wonder what you would do if, in 'answering' this question, I instead took some time to criticize Sade for doing poorly what it took Conrad to properly set down in A Hero with a Thousand Faces (a deliberately inaccurate statement). The problem I see with this answer is twofold: it doesn't answer the question the OP asked, and its content is overly subjective, more akin to a rant, a blog post, or an obscure and opinionated newsletter. If you would like to try to salvage your answer, I encourage you to concentrate on the content of the question, rather than spurious or weakly related topics.

Comment: @mixedmath: How is it inaccurate? Have you compared Sade to Nietzsche? I can even _source_ the statement that Nietzsche's philosophy is derived from sexual sadism--- it is explicitly made by several prominent anti-Nietzsche scholars. I am not saying something new here. There is no problem in your writing wrong things on stackexchange, they get downvoted when they are wrong (and also sometimes when they are right). The only problem is when people don't allow honest response. I am answering the question directly--- read Geneoogy, and read Sade. That's the answer.

Comment: **That is not an answer to *which Nietzsche text* the person should read.** Look, I know it's a lot to ask, but we do require that you actually read the question.

Comment: @Ron: I was saying that comparing Sade to Conrad is inaccurate. Instead of continuing this comment thread, I would like to say that I find myself very much in line with Cody's answer.

Comment: @RonMaimon: Ok, I did look at it, and I honestly *did* try to salvage it (only seeing CodyGray's warnings in the comments *after* I already returned to type this), but honestly I just couldn't without having to delete all but half of the first line. It's not bad to suggest other authors which help in aiding understanding X asked-about author, but you don't indicate at all how reading Sade will actually help understand Nietzsche. Apparently they have similar ideas, sure, that doesn't automatically mean Sade is some magic gateway to Nietzsche. Just an aside — you know nothing about me. :)

Comment: @stoicfury: I wasn't talking about _you_, I was using the meaning of "generic you", if "one thinks one is superior, then one is not"... Sorry, I should have written that. So here is a person asking "what should I read?" I say "Geneology and Sade", and this is not allowed? What kind of ridiculousness is this.

Comment: @Ron It appears you've been reading my comments incorrectly. As I mentioned, it's not *bad* to suggest other authors which help in aiding understanding X-asked-about author, but since yours didn't really indicate to me why your suggested author would help understand Nietzsche, it was tangential to the question. If someone wanted to know what Kant books to read, it would be like me writing, "Read the Critique and also Seneca because the ideas are similar." Even if that was true (it's not), mere *similarity* just isn't enough to prove that it would help in understanding...

Comment: @stoicfury: I am saying "Read SADE because nietzsche is ripping him off!" By this I mean, if you read Sade, you don't even need to read nietzsche, because the philosophy is expressed far more clearly and more eloquently in Sade, further, without the all the f****** racism and anti-semitism. I don't understand what you can't understand--- I am saying that everything in nietzsche is contained in Sade, much earlier, much clearer, and with a better thinker and a better writer (except associated with the political left, as opposed to the right).

Comment: @Ron So, if you remove the entire first paragraph minus the section between the first set of commas, expand on why this particular work is one that represents a "good introduction", rewrite the second half in a non-degrading manner, and explain briefly why Sade helps in understanding Nietzsche (it's a side point, but if you've already answered the primary question it's ok), it will be an acceptable answer. I will personally reopen it if this is done satisfactorily.

Comment: @stoicfury: I do not want you to "salvage" anything--- I don't like the way you write, and I don't want my stuff toned down. I want a discussion on a meta-site about whether my answers are inappropriate. This answers the question correctly, and it would be _very helpful_ to OP. I know, because it was helpful to me in understanding where a shallow metally defective peice of s*** like Nietzsche could find such an original-seeming idea.

Comment: @stoicfury: I will not do that. I don't want a conversation with you, as I will never meet you half-way. I want to be left alone, and downvoted. I give good answers, and I do not intent to meet people who take nietzsche seriously in any sort of half-way position. I do not respect neitzsche, or anyone who _does_ respect neitzsche, and I am not going to start, ever. That means I want to discuss this on meta-meta, like stackexchange.

Comment: Try meta.stackoverflow.com or you can email the team directly (team+meta.philosophy@stackexchange.com) if you are concerned about moderator actions.

Comment: Yes, you should open up a question on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ if you are seriously intent in escalating this up a level, beyond the Philosophy.SE community and the local moderators. Like Shog9 says, that's the closest thing you're going to get to a Meta-Meta site.

Comment: Too bad that answer was deleted. I liked it.

Answer (score 7):

> My point here is that Nietzsche is not just a !@$#^@* Nazi #@&!, but he is a plagiarist as well.

Regardless of the veracity of this assertion, you've managed to find the one place where making such a claim is decidedly inappropriate.

**This is *not* an answer to the question**, "Which of Nietzsche's writings would be a good introduction to his work?" The person is not asking for a criticism of Nietzsche's writings, they're not asking for background information or context, and they're not asking for your pet interpretation of Nietzsche as a philosopher or as a man.

At a certain point, someone honestly has to say **that's enough**. You're entitled to an opinion, and you're entitled to state that opinion on a Philosophy Q&A site, so long as you follow the applicable guidelines (i.e., family-friendly language, appropriate citations, a constructive tone akin to that found in an academic journal, etc.). **But you are *not* entitled to repeat that opinion *ad nauseum* to every question that gets posted to this site with the [nietzsche](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nietzsche) tag.** (And mind you, that's not a new rule that we've created just for you. It goes for everyone, on every subject.)

Sure, I could tell you all of the other *specific* things that are wrong with your answer. Like the fact that you start with the completely uncalled for and unconstructive "If you insist on reading Nietzsche", and the fact that the entire first paragraph is a pointless, off-topic rant that amounts to nothing more than an *ad hominem* attack against Nietzsche as a person, and the fact that you admit *within the answer itself* that it's not a direct answer to the question that is being posed. But I'm not going to...

Comment: I explained--- to understand Nietzsche you need to read Sade. How is this not an answer? I began with Geneology, which is central to Nietzsche, and I said he's a one-trick pony. These assertions are very useful to those who are coming here looking for what to read, and you can let them make up their own mind, or just _downvote the answer_. Deletion is not appropriate, especially for a field with conflict of interest.

Comment: The only conflict of interest that exists here is between the interest of people who want useful answers to their questions, and your personal interests in lambasting Nietzsche.

Comment: There is no useful answer to Nietzsche questions other than "he's a fraud, don't waste your time". If you don't allow this answer, you are engaging in censorship. You can _downvote_ this answer, but it needs to be present, as it represents a reasonably founded point of view held by many. I want to discuss this on a meta-meta-site, the place where stackexchanges go for super-moderation. Where is this place?

Comment: I don't intend to stop answering questions from this position, ever, because I was forced to read this garbage as an undergrad, and write respectfully about it, and I couldn't, and I won't, and I am very proud of my near-failing grade in undergraduate philosophy. I don't want others to be forced to read and respect this Nazi b******* in class. It is in large part the reason there are no good philosophers today, outside of mathematical philosophy--- the good folks are purged by Nietzsche. Neitzsche is Fascism's last stand, and it's not an easy fight, but this web site is where it is fought.

Comment: The nearest thing to a meta-meta is http://meta.stackoverflow.com/, @Ron. Be warned - that site has a lot of traffic, and folks there tend to take a dim view of questions that take a while to get to the point or ignore past discussions. You might want to read this first: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer

Comment: *"I am very proud of my near-failing grade in undergraduate philosophy"* This is concerning to me. Not because I made perfect grades in all of my college classes (far from it), but because you seem to be *proud* of the fact that you made a bad grade and that *that* is your primary incentive for participating on a Philosophy Q&A site. In particular, it concerns me that **you're not here to *learn* anything**, like most everyone else. Rather, you're here to shove your admittedly limited knowledge down our throats. No one appreciates that. And that's something you need to understand.

Comment: If you're really concerned about the nature of philosophy and the long-standing impact of Nietzsche's works, @Ron, you should do something more constructive than repeatedly lambasting him to anonymous people on the Internet. In fact, you should try to move beyond criticizing him altogether, considering that he's already dead and the impact he's going to have on philosophy *has already been had*! You need to contribute something *new* to the field, something that goes *beyond* Nietzsche. Something that opens up a whole new post-Nietzschean horizon. The postmodernists did this quite well...

Comment: @RonMaimon: *"Neitzsche is Fascism's last stand, and it's not an easy fight, but this web site is where it is fought."*  Actually, this web site is **not** where it is fought, thank you very much.  There may be, somewhere, a Q&A site where "What does Ron Maimon think of Nietzsche?" is a relevant question, and clearly on *that* site yours would be a great answer.  But that's not here.

Comment: Interestingly, the postmodernists also have links to fascism, De Man was inspired by fascist thinking. The issue is always the denial of the role of God (ethical God, not supernatural God, they're different) in arranging human affairs. This is the main beef nazis had with the Jews, "inventing" God. The point that God is not of the Jews alone was lost upon them, and upon many others. [This website](http://startthinkingright.wordpress.com/2008/05/03/postmodernism-leads-to-fascism-p-3/) offers some interesting historical comments, although I do not agree with its right-wing politics at all.

Comment: Heck, *of course* the postmodernists have links to fascism. Very few of them deny it. A number of them *embrace* it. That's one of the questions I'd be asking if I really cared to understand this warped sense of philosophy: why do you just assume *a priori* that fascism is evil? Then again, the argument that "postmodernism leads to fascism" (and I'm being overly generous in calling it an "argument") is reductionism at its finest. For the record, I've read Paul de Man extensively and have quite an appreciation for his work. Doesn't mean I *agree* with it, but I do think it's interesting.

Comment: @CodyGray: I have contributed a new thing--- I have contributed the theory of asymmetric superrationality, detailed here: christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/6338/… . The interesting thing is that the non-ethical game-theoretic ethical system of non-symmetric superrationality allows you to make sense of the notion of God without any supernatural or implausible assumptions, only that there exists a superrational strategy for arbitrary games. This essentially solves the problem of religion and of ethics at once